# How to find the value of '_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI' of a shared object?

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, anaconda

I am using Python 3.7 from Anaconda3 v5.3, which was built with gcc 7.2, on Redhat 7.5 ppc64le which is built with gcc 4.8.4.

I built pyarrow in this environment, but I keep getting the following error on doing import pyarrow.

```
$ python
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 13:02:24)
[GCC 7.2.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyarrow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/bsyu/files/arrow/python/pyarrow/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
 from pyarrow.lib import cpu_count, set_cpu_count
 ImportError: /home/bsyu/files/arrow/python/pyarrow/lib.cpython-37m-powerpc64le-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK5arrow11StructArray14GetFieldByNameERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

I see this is a very common error from linking shared objects built with different versions of gcc.  I tried building pyarrow with gcc 7.2, but it ends up with another undefined symbol error.

```
ImportError: /home/bsyu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/libparquet.so.12: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost13match_resultsIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEESaINS_9sub_matchISB_EEEE12maybe_assignERKSF_
```

I have two questions :

1. What is the general recommendation when we use Anaconda3 v5.3 on Redhat 7.5 ?  Use gcc 7.2 ?  Use `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` ?  Doesn't it bother you with these undefined symbol errors ?
2. How do we find the value of _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI used for a shared object ?   I tried strings, but it shows a bunch of nothing only.

```
$ strings /home/bsyu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/libparquet.so.12.0.0 | grep CXXABI
CXXABI_1.3.11
CXXABI_1.3.2
CXXABI_1.3
CXXABI_1.3.3
CXXABI_1.3.5
```

Comment: Generally, you use the same version of compiler and options for everything you link together. I know of no way to extract these defines from compiled code.

Comment: @rubenvb  Then do you recommend Anaconda 5.0 only, not Anaconda 5.2 or higher for Redhat 7.5 ?

Comment: I recommend using the same version of the compiler. The path of least resistance is using your distro's packages (if anaconda is in there, use that). I know RedHat has several GCC versions installable, maybe the one you want can be installed and set as default? I'm not that familiar with RedHat and that in itself warrants another question :) as this is all relatively off-topic for this question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `strings your.so | grep cxx11` because std::string is mangled to name `...cxx1112basic_string...` in cxx11 abi, while `...s...` in legacy abi.

But keep in mind that if your program doesn't use `std::string` you may be not able to tell the value of `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI`, for example: `int myfun(int num)` is mangled to `_Z5myfuni` in both legacy and cxx11 ABI